# Is there a way to disable or disallow gdb or lldb access to my compiled library?

Tags: c, gdb, lldb

Basically, all i would like to do is to make sure no one is able to step through sensitive code.

I read somewhere it was possible, only i can't find where i read that.

thanks!

Comment: it is possible to confuse the debugger but you can't stop others to break your binary

Comment: @BryanChen How can I confuse the debugger?  I'll take that :).

Answer (score 1):

No. Fundamentally, anyone who can run the object code can inspect it to any degree.

If you don't want them to be able to run the object code, you have to run it on a machine of your choice, and only interact with the user over a network.

All techniques that claim to disable debuggers simply exploit bugs, which are usually fixed a few months later when the next version of the debugger is released; and even those are completely useless against debugging through a VM.

Comment: "All techniques that claim to disable debuggers simply exploit bugs" -- you are way overgeneralizing. There are many techniques that don't exploit any bugs, but make debugging quite a lot harder. None of them make debugging impossible though, so I agree with the spirit of your answer.

Comment: @EmployedRussian would u shed some light on how to make the debugging a lot harder, on top of removal of debugging symbols during build? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to do is to make sure no one is able to step through sensitive code.

The "no one" part is impossible: a sophisticated attacker will be able to do it no matter what you try.

There are many techniques that will stop less sophisticated attacker, [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886411794) shows some of them.

Generally, these techniques are not worth your time -- they make field support of your software hard, they don't stop sophisticated attacker (and you only need one to succeed to render your efforts useless), and your software usually isn't that interesting to begin with.

If it is useful enough, people will buy it. If it is not, adding protections will make it even less useful.